# Cannot find module 'electron'

Tags: node.js, npm, atom-editor, electron

I'm working on a Node.js app that's using the "0.34.3" version of Electron.

The problem that I'm having is that when I try to include the 'electron' module in a renderer process as follows `require('electron').remote;` and when I `npm start`--I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'electron' from '/Users/waley/code/PROJECT/src/connect']
  stream: 
   Labeled {
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object] ],
     length: 1,
     label: 'deps' } }
[11:36:40] js error Cannot find module 'electron' from '/Users/waley/code/PROJECT/src/connect
```

Any idea what's up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

there are a few ways to resolve electron modules import regarding to [API Changes Coming in Electron 1.0](http://blog.atom.io/2015/11/17/electron-api-changes.html).

Please notice this usually occurs with bundler like webpack who override the `require` function.

#### Make use of Webpack's `target` property

If you are using a recent version of Webpack as a bundler, adding

```
target: 'electron-renderer'
```

to your config should let you use:

```
import 'electron' from electron;
```

#### Declare `electron` outside of your build

```
<!-- electron declaration -->
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
</script>

<!-- your app build -->
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

This way, I can access `electron` from anywhere.

#### Use the `window.require`

Electron extended the `window` object so that you could use:

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
```

#### Use the old way (still supported)

```
var remote = require('remote');
var app    = remote.app; // to import the app module, for example
```

Comment: I removed this solution as it seems to not working for everyone. And imo it's not a good practice. See the new solution I've given.

Comment: this works for me: const electron = window.require('electron'); which I can use straight inside my modules without making it global

Comment: Thanks @CatalinEnache, I added this solution to the answer !

Answer (score 14):

Run this command:

```
npm install --save-dev electron
```

for more details [click here](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I forgot to add `"main": "./main.js",` to `package.json` somewhere before scripts.
For complete setup follow this great [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/)

**Edit:**

Here's a summery of that link:

**Install Electron**

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

**Update index.html**

The generated root page in Angular points the base href to / - this will cause problems with Electron later on, so let’s update it now. Just add a period in front of the slash in src/index.html.

```
<base href="./">
```

**Configure Electron**

Create a new file named `main.js` in the root of your project (at the same level as `package.json`) - this is the Electron NodeJS backend. This is the entry point for Electron and defines how our desktop app will react to various events performed via the desktop operating system.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, 
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`
  })


  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)

  //// uncomment below to open the DevTools.
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Event when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })
}

// Create window on electron intialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  // On macOS specific close process
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // macOS specific close process
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Add `main.js` and custom scripts to `package.json`.
Your `package.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "main.js", // <-- update here
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .", // <-- run electron 
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron ." // <-- build app, then run electron 
  },
  // ...omitted
}
```

Run the command to build and launch electron

```
npm run electron-build
```